# Making an asyncio event loop respond to KeyboardInterrupt on Windows (and Unix)

Tags: python, signals, python-asyncio

When my program receives a KeyboardInterrupt, I want to call a piece of code (`self.client.logout()`) that will prompt the task running in my loop to gracefully exit.

This is my basic loop:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(self.client.start(token))
```

I initially tried to simply handle a `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(self.client.start(token))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    loop.run_until_complete(self.client.logout())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

But there is a large delay (variable, ≈1 minute) between pressing Ctrl+C and `self.client.logout()` being called.

I managed to get the effect that I wanted on Unix systems by adding handlers for `SIGINT`/`SIGTERM`:

```
import signal

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# enable the bot to respond to SIGINT/SIGTERM (Unix only)
try:
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(self.client.logout())
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(self.client.logout())
except NotImplementedError:
    pass   # program is running in Windows - nothing we can do

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(self.client.start(token))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    loop.run_until_complete(self.client.logout())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

When I press Ctrl+C or stop the systemd daemon running the program, the logout function gets called immediately.

What can I do to achieve the same thing on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Late but, you probably have a lot of blocking or high cpu functions running without space for the KeyboardInterrupt. Asyncio does have problems with Windows and KeyboardInterrupts though, so the event loop can sometimes hang, but using `self.client.run_until_complete(self.client.start(token))` as you have should mitigate or remove those issues, at least in my experience. But calls to `loop.run_forever()` have always had a small chance of missing the interrupt and leaving the program hanging.